# Number of finite elements

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm attempting to find the number of finite elements in a matrix in C++ using Armadillo. Assuming a double matrix `y`, I would think I could do so with (inside a mex function)

```
mexPrintf("finite_y: %g\n", (double) accu(find_finite(y)));
```

But this returns

```
[Matlab] finite_y: 1.41381e+09
```

However, I can get it to work with

```
mat y_ones = mat(y.n_rows, y.n_cols, fill::ones);
mexPrintf("finite_y (sum-ones): %g\n", accu(y_ones(find_finite(y))));

[Matlab] finite_y (sum-ones): 53150
```

How can I use `accu` with `find_finite` to get the number of finite elements in a matrix without creating a matrix of ones?

Comment: The casting of the result of `accu()` to `double` looks suspect. The output of `find_finite()` is a vector with `uword` elements, so the output of `accu()` is `uword` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_finite` returns a vector of type `arma::uvec`, which is a typedef for `arma::Col<uword>`. Every object `Col` has an attribute `.n_elem` which indicates the vector's length. Because `find_finite()` returns a vector that contains the indices of elements of X(argument) that are finite, one can simply assign that vector to a variable of type `arma::uvec`, or construct a copy of the resulting vector, and call its attribute `.n_elem` to tell us the amount of elements it has.

Also, if you want to use `accu()` you can assign the resulting vector from `find_finite()` to a `uvec` let's call it for example `arma::uvec newvector;`, then use its member function `newvector.ones()` which will set all its elements to 1. Then use `accu(newvector)`, which is similar to what you did.

Disclaimer: I've previously used Armadillo some time ago, might be outdated.